# How to make a IIS Site/Content Backup?

Tags: iis, backup

i want to learn ASP.NET, for this, i read some basic tutorials for managing the IIS Web-Server. Im Wondering how i could make a full backup of my site (Configuration and Content). Im running the IIS Server on a Hyper-V Windows Server 2012R2 Core and administrating over Powershell Remote.

In the Intenet, ifound an article about some basic stuff ([see here](http://windowsitpro.com/article/windows-powershell/microsoft-internet-information-services-iis-powershell-144224))

This Article said, i can make a full backup of my IIS Configuration and Content over

```
Backup-WebConfiguration -Name "My Backup"
```

And Restore it over

```
Restore-WebConfiguration -Name "My Backup"
```

The Problem is: It seems it really only makes backup from the Configuration and not from the Content. For Example: It Restores the Websites from IIS:\Sites but not the physical stuff like an Application Folder in it and a default.htm. If i delete the default .htm and the folders, use the Restore-WebConfiguration, it still does not restore it - only the WebConfiguration itself.

From the Articel i guessed, it would be restore also the content ....
Did i make something wrong? How can i do what i want "from scratch" without Scripts from MS Web Deploy 3.0 ?

thanks for help and best regards,

Answer (score 4):

Backup-WebConfiguration only backs up the configuration items detailed in the applicationHost.config file. It does not deal with the actual content, just how that content is handled by IIS.

To do both is easy enough, here's a quick function that creates a zip file (just enter in the path to your inetpub directory) and backs up the configuration. (This requires Powershell v3 or higher) The backup will have a Creation Date automatically set for it (you can see a list of your backups by using the [Get-WebConfigurationBackup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790587.aspx), so this goes ahead and adds the date and time to the zip file as well so they can be matched up.

If you're making more than one backup in the same day, you'll need to tweak the file name of the compressed file as it only has the date in its file name.

```
function Backup-WebServer
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]            
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [string]$Source,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [string]$Destination,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ConfigurationName
    )

    Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal

    $date = $(Get-Date -Format d).Replace('/','-')
    $fileName = "Inetpub-Backup $date.zip"

    $inetpubBackup = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $fileName

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source,$inetpubBackup,$compressionLevel,$false)

    Backup-WebConfiguration -Name $ConfigurationName

}
```

Comment: If i want backup site in scheduled manner, i can run this script using `Task Scheduler`.Is it right? @Paolis